# multiple clients need to connect to local HyperSQL 2.2.8 and write to hsqldb

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

My requirement is that multiple clients need to connect to local HyperSQL 2.2.8 and write.
There will also be a seperate client used for viewing on the same machine.
So multiple writer clients and one reader client need to be connected to local HyperSQL 2.2.8.
I am using hibernate to read and write from local HyperSQL 2.2.8.

I run hsldb as server like this
java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:mydb --dbname.0 xdb

My problem is the first client holds a lock when it connects.
The other clients are not able to write.

Appreciate any help on solving this.

Thanks
Bala

Comment: Sounds like the first client isn't comitting the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After starting the server, you connect to it with the URL `jdbc:hsqldb:hsq://localhost/xdb`. If the reader client performs long-running queries, you should create the database with MVCC or MVLOCKS transaction models. See the Guide: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sessions-chapt.html#snc_tx_tx_cc

Comment: Hi Fredt, Thanks for your comment. I did connect with jdbc:hsqldb:hsq://localhost/xdb and first client succeeds. But the next client gets a locked exception and I can see a lck file created on the filesystem.

Comment: It works if you run the server only once then connect to the server from all clients. The locked exception is because you are using jdbc:hsqldb:file: to connect the second time

Comment: Hi Fred, Thanks a lot - that clarifies things. Appreciate your help much.

Comment: Hi, I create database with java org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:C:\Documents and Settings\BThirup\Application Data\R\F\logs\ApplicationLog\mydb;shutdown=true --dbname.0 xdb and then try to connect with 'jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb'. This fails with Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@3908b689[file =... .Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The lockFile exception is thrown only when a jdbc:hsqldb:file: URL is used. It cannot occur with the jdbc.hsqldb:hsql URL.

Comment: I removed the 'file:' as you suggested. I now start with this command:java org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:C:\Documents and Settings\BThirup\Application Data\Rockwell Automation\FactoryTalk ProductionCentre\logs\ApplicationLog\mydb;shutdown=true --dbname.0 xdb. I use jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb for connection but get "Environment Error initializing hsqldb in Environment.SEVERE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect".  I am thankful for your kind help

Comment: Perhaps the username or password is not correct. I suggest you start the server with --silent false and check further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use property `hsqldb.lock_file=false` (default is `true`)

> By default, a lock file is created for each file database that is opened for read and write. This property can be specified with the value false to prevent the lock file from being created. This usage is not recommended but may be desirable when flash type storage is used. This property applies to existing file: databases as well as new databases.

Please see http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html